# Comparing values and checking duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I'm facing an issue where I want to have an output telling me what files have the same inode, for example "filename1 and filename2 are the same". This would be if two inodes are the same, however I don't know how to apply this. I'm currently trying to make an array where the key is the name of the file and the value is the inode but it's not working (var_dump is just giving me an empty array).

If I somehow get the array to work then I am guessing I will need to increment through it somehow and check if two values are the same then print their keys.

```
    global $hardlink;
    $hardlink = [];

    foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
      file_info($filename);
      print_file_info();
    }

    var_dump($hardlink);
    exit(0);

    function file_info($name) {
      global $info;                
        $info[0] = $name;          // the file name
        $info[1] = filesize($name);  // file size
        $info[2] = filetype($name); // file type

        $cwd = getcwd();
        $path = "$cwd/$name";

        if(is_link($path)) {
            $link = readlink($path);
            $info[3] = "-> $link";
        } else {
            $info[3] = "No link";
        }

        $lstat = lstat($path);
        $info[4] = $lstat[1];

        $hardlink[$info[0]] = $info[4];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `$hardlink` to the global line in your function:

```
function file_info($name) {
    global $info, $hardlink;
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. If possible, could you suggest how I could check the two file inodes and have the keys printed of those same values? something like array_intersect? So I could have the output "these files possess the same inodes: filename1, filename2"

Comment: @Xylus, that is beyond the scope of the question, open a new question if you can't figure it out.  The PHP manuals have a lot of examples, but I hope you read and understand my answer as well.  If you want to write good code, you will avoid globals completely.

Comment: @Devon thanks again. I'll look over the PHP manuals and try to figure out the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have a general problem with your variable scope.  This is one of the many reasons why you should not rely on globals.

`$hardlink` is a local variable inside the function file_info(), not a global, therefore whatever changes you make will not present themselves in the global scope.

To better fix this issue, get rid of the global declarations and pass a reference.

```
$hardlink = [];

foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
  file_info($filename, $hardlink);
  print_file_info();
}

function file_info($name, &$hardlink) {
    $info[0] = $name;          // the file name
    $info[1] = filesize($name);  // file size
    $info[2] = filetype($name); // file type

    $cwd = getcwd();
    $path = "$cwd/$name";

    if(is_link($path)) {
        $link = readlink($path);
        $info[3] = "-> $link";
    } else {
        $info[3] = "No link";
    }

    $lstat = lstat($path);
    $info[4] = $lstat[1];

    $hardlink[$info[0]] = $info[4];
}
```

Notice that I have defined $hardlink as a reference in the second argument of the file_info function by prefixing it with an `&`.